# Count unique visits (by IP) from apache logs

Tags: awk, grep

I'm trying to calculate the number of unique visits on a URL from my apache logs.

Here is what I have so far:

```
grep -o 'THIS_IS_MY_URL' other_vhosts_access.log | wc -l
```

This is working, but I'm not filtering on unique IPs yet. Do you have any idea?

Thanks !

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input (contents of `other_vhosts_access.log` and example URL(s)), expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those log files are most of the time in the following format:

```
<IP> - - <TIMESTAMP> <METHOD> <URL> ....
```

---

So instead of just using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), we'll need some more:

1. Remove the `-o` from grep so we're getting the whole line where the matching URL is found
2. Then we can use `cut -d' ' -f1` to get only a list of IP addresses <sup>[[docs]](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)</sup>
3. Use the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) util `uniq` to filter it to only unique values <sup>[[docs]](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html)</sup>
4. Count the lines using `wc -l`

```sh
grep 'SEARCH ME' file.log | cut -d' ' -f1 | uniq | wc -l
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks you. In my case I had to replace -f1 by -f2. But it works well!

Comment: That would only work if the IPs are always grouped together. If you replace `uniq` with `sort -u` it'd be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is somewhat old now, however, thought I'd share this:

```
cat 'your_request.log' | awk {'print $1'} | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

It will count and numerically sort visiting IPs regardless of the URL.